# React - All of the states of OnFocus work at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having a problem while constructing signup page.

Specifically, i intended to make the form validation check function when i clicked the each input only.

However, it works all of the inputs together.

Could anyone let me know where to correct in my code?

Summary:

1. Want to make validation check function. It works seperatly for each input.
2. Made it, however, when i clicked any one of input, then all of the input's error has activated.
3. I can't find where it's error, guessing using only one state ? "const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);"
4. Additional info, i was able to find the focus function works, however, all of the inputs activated at all togehter... considering wether should i use seperate states for each values? And at the same time, there could be much clean, and neat way...!

Appreciate !

```
// Signup.css
span {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 3px;
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

input:invalid[focused="true"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input:invalid[focused="true"] ~ span {
  display: block;
}



//Signup.js

    function(props) {
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      const [id, setId] = useState("");
      const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
      const [passwordConfirm, setPasswordConfirm] = useState("");
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
      const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
      const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
    
    const handleFocus = (e) => {
        setFocused(true);
      };
    
    return (
        <>
          <div className='full-box'>
            <div id='signup-middle-box' className='middle-box'>
              <h2>SignUp</h2>
              <form onSubmit={SignUpUser}>
                <div id='signup-small-box' className='small-box'>
                  <div className='signup-box'>
                    <div className='signup-forms'>
                      <h6>ID</h6>
                      <div id='forms-with-button'>
                        <div className='forms-with-btn'>
                          <input
                            placeholder='ID'
                            value={id}
                            onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)}
                            type='text'
                            name='id'
                            id='Id'
                            onBlur={handleFocus}
                            focused={focused.toString()}
                            required
                          />
                          <span>
                            <img src={redWarning} alt={redWarning} />
                            Please fill ID
                          </span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <button onSubmit={CheckUser}>CheckUser</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div className='signup-forms'>
                      <div className='pw-box'>
                        <h6>Password</h6>
                        <p>
                          <img src={warning} alt={warning} /> Password should be 8-20 characters and include at least 1 letter, 1 number and 1 special character!
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div className='forms-without-btn'>
                        <input
                          placeholder='Please type password'
                          value={password}
                          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                          type='password'
                          name='password'
                          id='password'
                          autoComplete='off'
                          pattern={`^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,20}$`}
                          onBlur={handleFocus}
                          focused={focused.toString()}
                          required
                        ></input>
                        <input
                          placeholder='Repeat the password'
                          value={passwordConfirm}
                          onChange={(e) => setPasswordConfirm(e.target.value)}
                          type='password'
                          name='passwordConfirm'
                          id='pwRepeat'
                          autoComplete='off'
                          onBlur={handleFocus}
                          focused={focused.toString()}
                          pattern={`^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,20}$`}
                          onFocus={() =>
                            password === "passwordConfirm" && setFocused(true)
                          }
                          required
                        ></input>
                        <span>
                          <img src={redWarning} alt={redWarning} />
                          Passwords don't match !
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div className='signup-forms'>
                      <h6>Name</h6>
                      <div className='forms-without-btn'>
                        <input
                          placeholder='Type your name'
                          value={name}
                          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                          type='text'
                          name='name'
                          id='Name'
                          autoComplete='off'
                          pattern={`^[가-힣]{2,4}$`}
                          focused={focused.toString()}
                          onBlur={handleFocus}
                          required
                        ></input>
                        <span>
                          <img src={redWarning} alt={redWarning} />
                          Check your name
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div className='signup-forms'>
                      <h6>Phone</h6>
                      {isPhonecertiOn === true ? (
                        <PhoneCertificate
                          isPhonecertiOn={isPhonecertiOn}
                          setPhoneCertiOn={setPhoneCertiOn}
                        />
                      ) : (
                        <div id='forms-with-button'>
                          <div className='forms-with-btn'>
                            <input
                              // style={style}
                              placeholder='Enter your phone'
                              value={phone}
                              onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
                              type='text'
                              name='phone'
                              id='Phone'
                              autoComplete='off'
                              pattern={`^(010|011|016|017|018|019)[0-9]{3,4}[0-9]{4}$`}
                              focused={focused.toString()}
                              required
                            ></input>
                            <span>
                              <img src={redWarning} alt={redWarning} />
                              Phone has 11 digits
                            </span>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <button
                              id='phone-certification'
                              onClick={() => setPhoneCertiOn(true)}
                            >
                              <img src={phone_certi} alt={phone_certi} />
                              Phone Certification
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <span>
                      <img src={redWarning} alt={redWarning} />
                      Phone has 11 digits.
                    </span>
    
                    <div className='signup-forms'>
                      <h6>Email</h6>
                      {isEmailcertiOn === true ? (
                        <EmailCertificate
                          isEmailcertiOn={isEmailcertiOn}
                          setEmailcertiOn={setEmailcertiOn}
                        />
                      ) : (
                        <div id='forms-with-button'>
                          <div className='forms-with-btn'>
                            <input
                              // style={style}
                              placeholder='Type your email'
                              value={email}
                              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                              type='text'
                              name='email'
                              id='email'
                              autoComplete='off'
                              onBlur={handleFocus}
                              focused={focused.toString()}
                              required
                            ></input>
                            <span>
                              <img src={redWarning} alt={redWarning} />
                              Please enter exact email form
                            </span>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <button
                              id='email-certification'
                              onClick={() => setEmailcertiOn(true)}
                            >
                              <img src={email_certi} alt={email_certi} />
                              Email certification
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
    
                    <div className='signup-forms'>
                      <button id='signup-btn'>Submit</button>
                      <button
                        id='signup-cancle-btn'
                        onClick={() => {
                          props.setFormsOn(false);
                        }}
                      >
                        Cancle
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
    }
```

Comment: the problem is occurring because the same [focused] state is being used for all input fields

Comment: you can try making seperate states for each input or use an object `focused: { input1: boolean, input2: boolean, input3: boolean}`

Comment: Thanks for the comments Kritiz !
Will try to make focused value for each.

Comment: I updated the state as follow,

  const [focused, setFocused] = useState({
    id: false,
    name: false,
    email: false,
    password: false,
    passwordConfirm: false,
    phone: false,
  });

And, not sure how to update 'onBlur={handleFocus}' part in input tag, could you let me know wehther i'm doing right?

Comment: handleFocus also needs to be updated... for example: `handleFocus = (inputType) => { setFocused(oldData=>( {...oldData, [inputType]: !oldData[inputType] } ) }`. In the same way, `<input type="email" onBlur={ () => handleFocus("email") }` and similarly for other inputs

Comment: Thanks for the comment again, i found what the problem was it.
I was lack of class and instance, which means kinda lack of Object Programing !
The thing i was doing worngly was using same state for all of inputs, not each input works seperatly!
Again, thanks for your help !

Comment: Hello Kritiz, i'm wondering where can i find the function that returns comparsion's result between pattern and onChange value of input in this code. Do you know any thing relate to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the most comprehensive solution to this problem is as follows:

Have a isValid state for each form input.

Have the validation check function sets the isValid state for all inputs.

I have an example of a form component that you can use as a reference although it is implemented in typescript so the syntax will be slightly different.

### Example

```
const LoginForm = ({email, setEmail, password, setPassword, onLogin, loading}: LoginFormPropTypes) => {
    
    const [isVisiblePassword, setIsVisiblePassword] = useState(false);
    const [validEmail, setValidEmail] = useState(true);
    const [emailHelper, setEmailHelper] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [validPassword, setValidPassword] = useState(true);
    const [passwordHelper, setPasswordHelper] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const {colors} = useTheme();

    // Setting form validation states and helperText using validator
    const validateForm = (input: 'email' | 'password' | 'all') => {
        let allowSubmit = true;
        if(input === 'email' || input === 'all') {
            if(!validator.isLength(email, {min: 1})) {
                setValidEmail(false);
                setEmailHelper('Email field cannot be empty');
                allowSubmit = false;
            } else if(!validator.isEmail(email) || !validator.isLength(email, {max: 320})){
                setValidEmail(false);
                setEmailHelper('The Email provided is invalid');
                allowSubmit = false;
            } else {
                setValidEmail(true);
            }
        }
        if(input === 'password' || input === 'all') {
            if(!validator.isLength(password, {min: 1})) {
                setValidPassword(false);
                setPasswordHelper('Password field cannot be empty');
                allowSubmit = false;
            } else if(!validator.isLength(password, {max: 200})) {
                setValidPassword(false);
                setPasswordHelper('Password exceeds maximum length of 200')
                allowSubmit = false;
            } else {
                setValidPassword(true);
            }
        }
        return allowSubmit;
    }

    // Checking if form is valid before submitting
    const onSubmitHandler = () => {
        if(validateForm('all')){
            onLogin?.();
        }
    }


    return (
        <CardWrapper>
            <Card.Content>
                <TextInput
                    label="Email"
                    mode="outlined"
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    onChangeText={setEmail}
                    value={email}
                    dense
                    error={!validEmail}
                    onBlur={() => {validateForm('email')}}
                />
                <HelperText 
                    type="error" 
                    visible={!validEmail} 
                    style={{display: !validEmail ? undefined : 'none'}} 
                >
                    {emailHelper}
                </HelperText>
                <TextInput
                    label="Password"
                    mode="outlined"
                    style={{...styles.textInput, ...styles.marginTop}}
                    onChangeText={setPassword}
                    value={password}
                    dense
                    secureTextEntry={!isVisiblePassword}
                    onBlur={() => {validateForm('password')}}
                    right={
                        <TextInput.Icon 
                            color={(isFocused) => 
                                validPassword 
                                    ? (isFocused ? colors.primary : 'black')
                                    : colors.error
                            }
                            forceTextInputFocus={false}
                            onPress={() => setIsVisiblePassword(!isVisiblePassword)} 
                            name={isVisiblePassword ? "eye-off" : "eye"}
                        />
                    }
                    error={!validPassword}
                />
                <HelperText 
                    type="error" 
                    visible={!validPassword} 
                    style={{display: !validPassword ? undefined : 'none'}} 
                >
                    {passwordHelper}
                </HelperText>
                <Button 
                    style={{marginTop: 15}}
                    mode="contained" 
                    onPress={onSubmitHandler} 
                    loading={loading}
                >
                    Login
                </Button>
            </Card.Content>
        </CardWrapper>
    );
    
};
```